# How to get and set state of Flip Switch Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intel-xdk, appframework

```
<div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_14 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/flip_switch" data-ver="1">
    <label class="narrow-control label-inline">Available</label>
        <div class="wide-control">
             <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="driveravailable">
              <label for="driveravailable" data-off="No" data-on="Yes"><span></span>
              </label>
         </div>
</div>
```

I had HTML code for flip switch in Intel XDK using App Framework like above.

I am unable to get the value from Flip switch in my javascript by:

```
alert($('#driveravailable').val());
```

and I can't set the state for Flip switch like:

```
$('#driveravailable').val('no').flipswitch('refresh');
```

What should I do?? I am so sorry about my not good English.
I greatly appreciate your answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the resolution like this:

```
if($('#driveravailable').is(":checked")) {
    $('#driveravailable').prop("checked", false);
} else {
    $('#driveravailable').prop("checked", true);
}
```

behave it like a Checkbox